# Redundant Casting in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casting

Im working out a compression ratio and I noticed that I have a "Redundant Cast" in this line:

```
double ratio = (double)data.Length / (double)comp.Length;
```

Obviously dividing both array lengths without casting to double will return only the integer component of the number.

But why is this cast redundant?

Having just one cast on one Length removes the warning.

To my understanding if we had:

```
double ratio = (double)data.Length / comp.Length;
```

or

```
double ratio = data.Length / (double)comp.Length;
```

wouldnt that then potentially cause another developer to get confused about what value is being calculated here.

It seams to me that having an implicit cast can cause code readability issues. Especially in more complex one line calculations (which really is another readability question).

I also thought casting values to different forms produce different outputs depending on where the cast is made in the equation.

Comment: Well it _is_ redundant, that is - adding or removing that cast has no effect on the result. Redundancy has no relation to readability in this case. Also the fact it is redundant does not mean it's necessary bad thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "I haven't the manual" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer, I can say that

```
double ratio = (double)data.Length / comp.Length;
```

or

```
double ratio = data.Length / (double)comp.Length;
```

Will never confuse me. I recoginze this "pattern":

1. Division operation
2. One operand is casted to `double`

So, I understand, that second operand and result are double. And I (as developer) don't need second cast operator.

Comment: I suppose in this case - its subjective to the developers experience in coding and also the language you use.

Comment: @Gelion I think, some subjective experience became live standarts, like naming conventions and so on